# TypeScript: is there a way to use the JSDOC @deprecated tag to mark a symbol imported from a module as deprecated?

Tags: typescript, jsdoc

I would like to mark a symbol as deprecated when imported from an 3rd party module.
In the following example `bar` is some npm module that exports the function `foo` and I would like to mark `foo` as deprecated to inform that this api should no longer be used.

```js
import {foo} from 'bar';

foo();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the [`@deprecated`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/jsdoc-supported-types.html#deprecated) tag must be written at the declared site of the symbol that's imported.

I tried creating two test repos and used declaration merging with [`declare module...`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/templates/module-d-ts.html), but got the following error:

> Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'foo'. ts(2451)

As a workaround, you can import the function in your own module and assign it to a new variable, applying whatever documentation you'd like — then re-export it for use in your other modules. For example:

`./src/bar.ts`:

```ts
import { foo as fooImport } from "bar";

/** @deprecated */
export const foo: typeof fooImport = fooImport;
```

`./src/another_module.ts`:

```ts
import { foo } from "./bar";

foo();
//^? Will have the @deprecated JSDoc
```